# render data in FlatList React Native (expo cli) from firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I'm working on a ToDo app that is connected to the Firebase real-time database. Everything works fine. I can also store data in the Firebase database, but the problem is that I cannot get any data from the database. I want to render data in ScrollView so that the data can be displayed in ScrollView when I open my app.

I'm getting error: **ReferenceError: noteArray is not defined <FlatList data={noteArray}**

I have uploaded my whole code [codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-snowflake-1lddp?file=/src/App.js][1]

**Main.js**

```
             import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      TextInput,
      TouchableOpacity,
      FlatList
    } from "react-native";
    import Note from "./note";
    import firebase from "./firebase";
    
    export default class Main extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          noteArray: [],
          noteText: ""
        };
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        this.listenForNotes();
      }
    
      listenForNotes() {
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref(`todos`)
          .on("value", function (snapshot) {
            const notes = [];
            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
              notes.push({
                note: child.val().name,
                date: child.val().date,
                key: child.key
              });
            });
            this.setState({
              noteArray: notes
            });
          });
      }
    
      adTask() {
        if (this.state.noteText) {
          var date = new Date();
          var database = firebase.database().ref("todos");
          var key = database.push().key;
          var todo = {
            date:
              date.getDay() +
              "/" +
              (date.getMonth() + 1) +
              "/" +
              date.getFullYear(),
            note: this.state.noteText,
            key: key
          };
          database.child(key).set(todo);
          this.setState({ noteText: "" });
        }
      }
    
      deleteNote(key) {
        // your delete note function
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
              <Text style={styles.headerText}>Todo</Text>
            </View>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.noteArray}
              renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                return (
                  <Note
                    key={item.key}
                    note={item.note}
                    date={item.date}
                    deleteMethod={() => this.deleteNote(item.key)}
                    />
                );
              }}
              key={(item) => `${item.key}`}
            />
            <View style={styles.footer}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                onChangeText={(noteText) => this.setState({ noteText })}
                value={this.state.noteText}
                placeholder="Enter Task"
                placeholderTextColor="white"
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              ></TextInput>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={this.adTask.bind(this)}
              style={styles.addButton}
            >
              <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>Add</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

**note.js**

```
            import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

export default class Note extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { note, date, key, deleteMethod } = this.props;
    return (
      <View key={key} style={styles.note}>
        <Text style={styles.noteText}>{note}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.noteDate}>{date}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={deleteMethod} style={styles.noteDelete}>
          <Text style={styles.noteDeleteText}>
            <AntDesign name="delete" size={24} color="black" />
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  note: {
    position: "relative",
    padding: 20,
    paddingRight: 100,
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: "#ededed"
  },
  noteText: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    borderLeftWidth: 10,
    borderLeftColor: "#e91e63"
  },
  noteDate: {
    paddingLeft: 20,
    borderLeftWidth: 10,
    borderLeftColor: "#e91e63"
  },
  noteDelete: {
    position: "absolute",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#2980b9",
    padding: 10,
    top: 10,
    bottom: 10,
    right: 10
  },
  noteDeleteText: {
    color: "white"
  }
});

    
    
      [1]: http://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-snowflake-1lddp?file=/src/App.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `this.state.noteArray` since noteArray is a state variable.

there are couple of errors in the code sandbox

```
    <FlatList
      data={noteArray}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
```

should be

```
  <FlatList
      data={this.state.noteArray}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
```

and key, should be item.key:

```
            deleteMethod={() => this.deleteNote(key)}
```

should be

```
            deleteMethod={() => this.deleteNote(item.key)}
```

this.setState doesn't exist is because you have a function instead of an array function. change it to the following should work:

```
  .on("value",  snapshot => {
    const notes = [];
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      notes.push({
        note: child.val().name,
        date: child.val().date,
        key: child.key
      });
    });
    this.setState({noteArray: notes});
  });
```

Comment: I checked your code but now it's giving this error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null.
 this.setState({ noteArray: notes });

Comment: my changes above doesn't involve changing setState. what are you seeing this?

Comment: That's the issue. I don't understand this error

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-snowflake-1lddp?file=/src/Main.js

check this link again there is an error:

Comment: I see this error after changing noteArray to this.state.noteArray.

Comment: did changing the callback function to array function fixed your issue?